# What is a more elegant way in Java to read line and combine duplicate entries based on one of the fields

Tags: java, readline

The following Java code reads lines from an input text file and will output the entry that has the highest number in field-2 to an output file.

**INPUT:**
William J. Clinton  6   Q1124
42nd President of the United States 6   Q1124
Bill Clinton,6,Q1124
Bill Clinton,14,Q9890
Bill Clinton,5,Q9880
William Jefferson Clinton,6,Q1124

**OUTPUT:**
William J. Clinton,Q1124
42nd President of the United States,Q1124
Bill Clinton,Q9890 (this Q-ID selected because field-2 was highest number "14")
William Jefferson Clinton,Q1124

**Is there a more elegant way than the approach I used in the following code that would produce the same output?**

```
/*
 * This class uses a method to combine duplicate Wiki keys into one and
 * selecting the Qid of the one with largest link count
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length < 2) {
        usage();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //
    try {
        // Create output file
        BufferedWriter out = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(args[1]),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        // read input file
        BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(args[0]),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String key = "";
        int links = 0;
        String qID = "";

        String next, line = br.readLine();
        for (boolean first = true, last = (line == null); !last; first = false, line = next) {
            last = ((next = br.readLine()) == null);

            String[] entry = line.split(",");

            if (first) {
                // only assign current values
                key = entry[0];
                links = new Integer(entry[1]);
                qID = entry[2];

            } else if (last) {

                //check if key is a duplicate
                if(key.equals(entry[0])){
                    //use the Qid from the highest links
                    int temp = new Integer(entry[1]);
                    if(links < temp){
                        //write entry to output higher links
                        out.write(key + "," + entry[2] + "\n");
                    }else{
                        //write entry to output using current
                        out.write(key + "," + qID + "\n");
                    }


                }else{
                    //write last entry to output
                    out.write(key + "," + qID + "\n");
                    out.write(entry[0] + "," + entry[2] + "\n");
                }

            } else {

                //check if key is a duplicate
                if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(entry[0])){
                    //use the Qid from the highest links
                    int temp = new Integer(entry[1]);
                    if(links < temp){
                        links = temp;
                        qID = entry[2];
                    }


                }else{
                    //write entry to output
                    out.write(key + "," + qID + "\n");

                    //reassign current values
                    key = entry[0];
                    links = new Integer(entry[1]);
                    qID = entry[2];
                }

            }   

        }

        // Close the output stream
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

private static void usage() {
    System.err.println("Usage: CombineKeys InputFile OutputFile");
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks you! I will try codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is a bit convoluted.  You might want to stick with a more conventional method for constructing a while loop.

i.e.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));
String sCurrentLine = "";

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
...
}
```

Comment: I started with a conventional for loop method, but could not figure out how to determine when the loop is ending to handle adding the last entry to the output file. Thanks!